# ASP.NET Request Validation Exception Even When Validation Is Disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2, .NET 4.0.

I have a controller that disables request validation:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Add(string userId, FormCollection formValues)
{
    //...
}
```

and I still get a HttpRequestValidationException when a POST contains HTML:

```
System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ThisWeek="").
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection nvc, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpRequestExtensions.GetHttpMethodOverride(HttpRequestBase request)
   at System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbsAttribute.IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.All[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelector.RunSelectionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 methodInfos)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedControllerDescriptor.FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.c__DisplayClass8.b__4()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I need to allow HTML text in the input here as the app is a bug tracking system and people talk about HTML in their bug submissions.  I am handling the inputs of this action correctly and appropriately encoding things as they are re-output, so it is reasonable to disable validation for this action.

We recently switched to MVC2 and .NET 4 and this started appearing.  From the stack trace, it appears that the validation is happening as part of processing of the new support for HTTP method overrides (making a POST look like a PUT or DELETE by including a specially named hidden input).  But I don't know how to tell that subsystem to stop validating the input.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: The answers are correct but wanted to add that if your using RenderAction you also have to disable any "child" validation from occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to `system.web` section of your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Yeah [.NET4 upped the security a bit](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/04/potentially-dangerous-request-net4.html). You can put it back to .NET2 mode in web.config like this:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
</system.web>
```