# Need to Save HTML markup from a form element

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, extjs, validation

I want to save html markup in my database for a field from an ASP.Net MVC2 application. Upon reading I found that using the [ValidateInput(false)] attribute lets you do that. But it is not working for me. The data comes from the extjs htmleditor form element.

Anyone has any ideas?  Is there something else I need to do? Any setting in web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [ASP.NET Request Validation Exception Even When Validation Is Disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522995/asp-net-request-validation-exception-even-when-validation-is-disabled/3523577)